# delete odd numbers in queue

Tags: java, queue, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

i am trying to delete odd numbers in the queue linked list but I am struggling to make function to
delete the odd here my code for better understanding ;

```
public class queueLinked {
    private Node rear;
    private Node front;
    private int siz;

    public boolean isEmpty() {//function return boolean if is empty or not
        boolean response = false;
        if (siz == 0) {
            response = true;
        }
        return response;
    }

    public void enqueue(int element) { // inserting the value type of int
        Node node = new Node(element);
        if (front == null) {
            rear = node;
            front = node;
        } else {
            rear.setNext(node);
            rear = node;
            siz++;
        }
    }

    public queueLinked() {
        front = null;
        rear = null;
        siz = 0;
    }

    public Node dequeue() { // to remove the a element in the queue
        Node response = null;
        if (front != null) ;
        if (front.getNext() != null) {
            response = new Node(front.getData());
            front = front.getNext();
            siz--;
        } else {
            response = new Node(front.getData());
            front = null;
            rear = null;
        }
        return response;
    }

    public Node peak() {
        Node response = null;
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            response = new Node(front.getData());
        }
        return response;
    }

    public int getSiz() { // to get the size
        return siz;
    }

    public void display() { // display the queue function
        System.out.print("\nQueue = ");
        if (siz == 0) {
            System.out.print("Empty\n");
            return;
        }
        Node ptr = front;
        while (ptr != rear.getNext()) {
            System.out.print(ptr.getData() + " ");
            ptr = ptr.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void deleteOdd() { // delete odd number in the queue
        System.out.print("\nQueue = ");
        if (siz == 0) { //make sure if it is empty or not
            System.out.print("Empty\n");
            return;
        }

        Node tempe = front;
        if (front.getData() % 2 != 0){
            enqueue(front.getData());
            front =  front.getNext();
            rear = rear.getNext();

        }
    }
}
```

in function `deleteOdd()` i tried to make sure if is it empty and then I tried more than way to get the right one if the first one is odd delete it  and front  = front.next and I do not know if it is right

Comment: do you want to delete all odd numbers from queue?

Comment: yes, i am trying to delete all odd in the queue

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function to delete odd number in queue.

```
 public void deleteOdd() { // delete odd number in the queue

    if (size == 0) { // make sure if it is empty or not
        System.out.print("Empty\n");
        return;
    }
    Node ptr = front;
    
    while (ptr != rear.getNext()) {
        
        if (ptr.getData() % 2 != 0) {   
            Node tmp = ptr.getNext();
            ptr.data = tmp.getData();
            ptr.next = tmp.next;
            size--;
        }
        else
            ptr = ptr.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println();
}


  QueueLinked queue = new QueueLinked();    
    
    for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
        queue.enqueue(i);
    }   
    
    queue.display();        
    queue.deleteOdd();
```

Comment: am getting  this message after running (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException)

Comment: before use deleteOdd, please insert some value to the queue.

Comment: it is printing the rear,  even if it is an odd number

Comment: Queue = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20, after delete
Queue = 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
size: 10

Answer (score 0):

First, there are some issues in other methods in your code:

### Issues

- `enqueue` should *also* increase the size of the list when adding to an empty list.
- `dequeue` should *also* decrease the size of the list when removing the last node from it.
- `dequeue` has a wrong semi-colon after `if (front != null) ;` and so you can get a null pointer exception on the line below it.

Here is a possible correction with minimal changes:

```
public void enqueue(int element) {
    Node node = new Node(element);
    if (front == null) {
        rear = node;
        front = node;
    } else {
        rear.setNext(node);
        rear = node;
    }
    siz++; // size should be updated in both cases
}

public Node dequeue() {
    Node response = null;
    if (front != null) { // correction of misplaced semi-colon
        response = new Node(front.getData());
        front = front.getNext();
        if (front == null) {
            rear = null;
        }
        siz--; // size should be updated in both cases
    }
    return response;
}
```

### deleteOdd

I chose to only use public methods of the class, so that this function can be easily coded outside of the class, if desired.

The current size of the queue is used for a count down, so every node is visited exactly once. The nodes with even data are appended to the queue again, but this count down will prevent us from visiting those again (and again, ...):

```
public void deleteOdd() {
    for (int count = getSiz(); count > 0; count--) {
        Node node = dequeue();
        if (node.getData() % 2 == 0) {
            enqueue(node.getData());
        }
    }
}
```